# What exactly is pi?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi, ratio

According to Wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi), pi is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Definition) as being the **ratio** of a circle's circumference to its diameter but also it is mentioned as an **irrational** number.

Also from Wikipedia (and high-school math), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number, an irrational number cannot be expressed as a **ratio**.

Therefore, how can *pi* be *irrational* and also a *ratio*? Don't they contrast? OR is the definition if pi wrong? If its a ratio shouldn't it be rational?

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article again: Irrational numbers cannot be expressed as the ratio of two **integers.**

Comment: Rational numbers are ratios *specifically using integers*.  Irrational numbers are able to be written as ratios, no problem... but the point is that if they *are* written as ratios then at least one of the numerator or denominator must not be an integer.

Comment: [Obligatory SMBC](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2011-04-08). See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_π_is_irrational).

Comment: So pi must be a ratio where either or both of numerator or denominator is irrational?

Comment: Every number $r$ can be written as a ratio , namely $\frac{r}{1}$. That does not imply any property of $r$ , in particular not that $r$ is rational.

Comment: Yes, an irrational number expressed as a ratio must have at least one of the numerator or denominator as irrational.  In the context of $\pi$ that means either the circumference of a circle is irrational, the diameter of the circle is irrational, or both.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It is earnestly someone who wants to understand maths, and not one of those "do my homework" questions we see so often.

Comment: I upvoted just because I had this same question when I was 14 and real numbers were introduced to us in school.

Comment: I agree with @Jean-ArmandMoroni. This question stems from a simple misconception, but I believe it's a well-formulated question that is asked in good faith. I had provided an answer so that the question could be resolved, but I deleted it because I was concerned about running afoul of the EoQS policy (even though I do not believe this question should fall under that policy).